# How to use Minecraft bedrock command block output as a variable?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am very familiar with Minecraft bedrock's command code, and I've used it for a long time. Although, I can't seem to figure out how to store the output from a command block into some kind of variable. I've looked it up, but the only result that might work is using the `/stats` command. The only problem is that this command is exclusive to the Java edition of the game. The specific way I'd like to use the output, is from a `/testforblocks` command. I'd like a command block to testforblocks in a certain area, compare the output to another `/testforblocks` command block, and then paste the answer in a `/title` command block. Put in other words,

If the result of (A > B) then A wins by (A - B), else if the result of (B > A) the B wins by (B - A)

The variable A being the result of blocks found in one area and variable B being the result of blocks found in another area.